# asynchronous iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

So I'm creating a code portfolio based upon what's in my svn repo.

I'm currently set up like this:

[image]

PHP loops through my JSON and creates these little menus for each file in each project. Here's some (very poorly structured) code showing how I generate each of these:

```
<form action = "" method = 'post'><select name = "s2" id = "s2"> <?php
    foreach($proj2->item_vers as $ver)
    {
         ?>
         <option value = <?php
         $base_str = (string)$ver->revision;
         $full_str = "\"".$base_str."\"";
         echo($full_str); ?> > <?php
         echo($base_str); ?> </option>
         <?php

    }   ?> </select><input type = 'submit'/></form>
        <a href = <?php
        if (isset($_POST['2']))
        {
             $rev2 = $_POST['s2'];
        }
        else 
             $rev2 = "";
        $full_url = "https://myrepo".
        $proj2->name."?p=".$rev2;
        $ret_url = "\"".$full_url."\"";
        echo($ret_url); ?> > Code </a></td>
```

So I have a `form`, `select`, `option`. The select will post the selected version from the drop down. Then I have a hyperlink which forms the correct url based upon the posted version number. This hyperlink will need to be replaced with an `iframe`. For the sake of simplicity, lets say that each project has its own iframe which is updated with appropriate project file any time you click one of the submit buttons.

So like this:

[image]

I'm looking for the simplest way to set this up to work asynchronously.

My thoughts:
I've already set up an asynchronous comment system using jQuery. The difference was that I only had three little `inputs` and a `button` to submit the comment. This just seems like it will be much more complicated as the code I posted above will loop through about 100 times. I cant just hard code a different id to every single submit button and write 100 different .js scripts to operate when each individual button is clicked.

Comment: slap an ID on that `<a>` tag. Use an AJAX request to fetch whatever you have to from the server, then it's a simple little bit of DOM mangling to delete the `<a>` and replace with an `<iframe>`, e.g. `$('#id_of_a_tag').replaceWith('<iframe ...>');`

Comment: I dont understand your problem. The above code create a single form, with a single select and a submit button. Yet you mention hundreds of submit buttons. Please include a more complete example and a thorough explanation of what you want to achieve. Im sure the answer will be a few lines of jquery with appropriate element targeting.

Comment: @user574632 I'm referring to the fact that the code I posted is in a loop. A form will be created for every single project file in my subversion repository. So I will have about a hundred instances of what I've shown up top. I.e. one for Assignment2.0/TestJSON.json, one for Assignment2.0/test_graph.py, etc. Sorry if that still doesn't clear things up.

Comment: @MarcB when you say fetch whatever you have to from the server, what do you mean? In this case I just need to set the src of the iframe to the link that I've created.

Comment: Sure, i kind of got that, but please edit your question with a more complete example. EG the code above contains fixed html IDs, so if its in a loop you have invalid duplicate ids, also what should happen when submit is pressed? Do you want one iframe on the page that changes or 100 different iframes? As it stands this question is too vague to answer

Comment: @user574632 I think I've clarified everything now.

Comment: OK, so if i have understood you, all you want to do is update the iframe at the bottom of the page, based on the option selected in one of many select boxes? If yes then i have an answer for you if not please just explain your question in plain english eg "i have 100 forms with a select box, when one form is submitted this must happen..."

Comment: @user574632 You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so im going to simplify your form generation code to make this clearer. I am including the outer loop you dont show:

```
<div id="forms-holder">
    <!--this is the outer loop-->
    <?php foreach ($projects as $project):?>

    <!-- remove any ids in the loop, they can not be duplicated-->  
    <form action="" class="projectform">

    <!-- add name to data attribute for easy retrieval by js-->
    <select name="s2" data-projectname="<?php echo $project->name;?>">
        <?php foreach ($project->item_vers as $ver):?>
        <option value="<?php echo'"'. $ver->revision .'"';?>"><?php echo $ver->revision;?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>

    <input type = 'submit'/>

    <form>

    <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" id="myiframe"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //when any form is submitted
        $('.projectform').submit(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();

            //grab revision and project name
            var revision = $(this).find('select').val();
            var projname = $(this).find('select').attr('data-projectname');

            //generate the url
            var iframeurl = "https://myrepo"+projname+"?p="+revision;

            //set the iframes url
            $('#myiframe').attr('src', iframeurl);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: almost perfect. I think there's a problem with this line. `var revision = $(this).find('select').val();` It doesn't seem to be taking in the revision number as intended. So the url ends up being `https://repo/?p=` every time. I've checked a few times, I don't think it's an error on my end.

Comment: @user2079802 Odd. Its very late here (UK) so i'll revisit this tomorrow. i'm sure we can fix it.

Comment: Well I managed to fix it somehow. `var revision = $(this).find('select').find(':selected').text()`. I've got no clue why it works, but solved. Anyway, cheers